# Find the number of ways to rearrange the word AARDVARK if ...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

a)No more than two As can appear together?

My Answer: I tried the complement. The total number of rearrangements minus if we glued the A's together and rearranged it that way. 
$$\binom 83\binom52\binom31\binom21\binom11-\binom62\binom41\binom31\binom21\binom11$$

b) each R must be preceded by an A

My Answer:I glued the R's with the A's (R-A), but that left me with one A left. Then I counted how many ways you could arrange each letter. The $\binom62$ is for the R-A's. $$\binom62\binom41\binom31\binom21\binom11$$

Not sure if these are correct or if there is another way to go about the problems. Please help me understand what I should be doing.

Note: Stirling numbers should not be used since my class it has yet to be discussed.

Comment: Both of your answers are correct, as the answers by Jack D'Aurizio and Atul Mishra confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(a)$.

Total words=$\frac{8!}{3!2!}$

words when three a's are together=$\frac{6!}{2!}$

Answer should be the difference of both .

For (b).

Total objects=$\{AR,AR,D,V,A,K\}$

the answer should be just $\frac{6!}{2!}$

Comment: Your answer to part (b) is correct.  In your answer to part (a), you also need to exclude the possibility that exactly two A's are adjacent.

Comment: But as I understood, two A's are allowed??@N.F.Taussig

Comment: Where is mistake in my understanding@N.F.Taussig??

Comment: I misread the question.  You are quite right.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ An anagram of $AARDVARK$ without consecutive $A$s is an anagram of $KRRDV$ (there are $\frac{5!}{2!}=60$ anagrams of $KRRDV$), like $DKRVR$, in which $3$ $A$s are inserted by substituting a separator like in $|D|K|R|V|R|$. There are $6$ separators, hence 
$$60\cdot\binom{6}{3} = 1200 $$
anagrams of $AARDVARK$ without consecutive $A$s. If there are exactly two adjacent $A$s, we have to choose where to insert an $AA$ character and where to insert an $A$ character by substituting a separator in something like $|D|K|R|V|R|$, with $6\cdot 5=30$ chances for doing that. It follows that the answer to point $(a)$ is $60\cdot(20+30)=3000$.
The answer to point $(b)$ is $\frac{6!}{2!}=360$ by just considering anagrams of the alphabet $\{AR,AR,A,D,V,K\}$.

Comment: The first question states that no more than two A's can appear together.  Your answer is valid if no two A's can be consecutive.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: right, I misread the question, now updating.